# How to disable the "highlight changes" feature?

Tags: notepad++

Our admins deployed a new version of Notepad++ (version 6.3) on our machines, and this version is highlighting all changes done in a file by default. It does so by setting the background color of every modified line to a bright orange, which I find very distracting.

We  have dozens of plugins installed, but I double checked and we do not have the "Change Markers" plugin (which could be the culprit).

Any idea where I can disable this feature? Changing the highlight color could also be an option.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I believe the plugin that is causing this background color change is "Location Navigate".
Check and see if this is installed. If so, click Plugins -> Location Navigate -> Show List and Option.
There will then be a drop box on the lower portion of the windows that says "Mark with Highlight".
You could then choose to change this to whatever suits your needs. I personally prefer mark with Rect.
It would then mark the changed lines with a rect bar in a margin on the left.

Alternatively, above the Dropbox option there are two options "Mark Color" & "Save Color". You could leave the Mark with Highlight option and just change the color of highlight...

I am 95 percent sure this will fix your issue.

Comment: Or to toggle on/off completely, select 'Plugins > Location Navigate > Mark Changed Line' ('Ctrl + Alt + M')

Comment: I spent at least 30 minutes trying to figure out what element of my style.xml file was making this happen. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks a ton for this! `+1` from me. I was just formulating such a question of my own when this one was suggested.

Comment: I have the same problem but no location navigate plugin

Comment: I have the same issue, and the resolution is perfect!

Comment: To access the "Mark Color" & "Save Color" options follow "Plugins" -> "Location Navigate" -> "Show List and Option". Look at the bottom of the oppened box (you may need to resize the Notepad ++ window). GPL License rules! =D

Comment: Setting or unsetting *Plugins > Location Navigate > Mark Changed Line* does not have any effect, changed lines are always highlighted in orange.

Comment: @Raketenolli Open the "Show List and Option" window, click on _Mark Color_ and select the color you want. If you don't want any marking, click the _Mark_ button (also toggled by _Mark Save Line_) to disable it (the button's color change is very slight) and future edits will not mark lines.

Comment: @Suncat2000 I have the same issue as _skan_ above: All lines with orange background, no _Location Navigate_ plugin installed. What now?

Comment: Disable it at all (also for printing): See FAQ https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/23616/faq-desk-new-change-history-feature