# Which Notepad++ plugin sets the text's background color to orange?

Tags: notepad++, colors, text-editing, background

I installed about two dozens of plugins in a new Notepad++ installation and the result is:

[image: Notepad++ orange text background]

I checked all plugins. None of them gives a hint to the background color. I also checked *Settings* →  *Preferences*. To no avail.

The *Change Markers* and *Location Navigate* plugins mentioned in [*How to disable the "highlight changes" feature?*](https://superuser.com/q/565785/516482) aren't shown in my *Plugins*.

**UPDATE**

`...\Notepad++\plugins`:

```
_CustomizeToolbar
AutoSave
BetterMultiSelection
BigFiles
CodeAlignmentNpp
ColumnTools
Comment Wrap
ComparePlugin
ComparePlus
Config
CsvQuery
CustomLineNumbers
doc
HexEditor
HTMLTag
HugeFiles
ImgTag
IndentByFold
JSFunctionViewer
JSMinNPP
JsonTools
mimeTools
nppAutoDetectIndent
NppConverter
NppExport
NppJavaPlugin
NPPJSONViewer
NppXmlTreeviewPlugin
XMLTools
```

Comment: What is the file extension?

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/q/75032400/372239

Comment: @DavidPostill `.txt`

Comment: @Toto The _sqlinform_ plugin is not in my  _Plugins_.

Comment: Can you tell us what plugins you _do_ have? Trying to find a needle in a haystack here, but at least we can reduce the haystack.

Comment: Who voted to close this Q and why?!?

Comment: How about going through and removing/disabling one plugin at a time until the undesired formatting goes away?

Comment: @music2myear https://superuser.com/a/1775003/516482 + comments

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes have this issue myself, and in my instance (I did disable all plugins without success) it was because something in Notepad++ had set the current document Language to JSON and (since the text is not JSON) Notepad++ is applying the JSON ERROR style.

[Notepad++ showing orange highlight due to JSON error highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0II10.png)

Notepad++ has somehow "autodetected" that this is a JSON document

[Notepad++ current document set to JSON language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU6si.png)

Notepad++ Settings->Style Configuration->Language:JSON->Style:ERROR

[Notepad++ JSON Error Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiU9y.png)

I've realized I get this issue whenever I have a text document containing a block of JSON and I've used the JSON Viewer plugin to format the block of JSON, which causes the whole document to be treated as JSON document.

Check if your document language has not been set to something other than "None (Normal Text)"

Answer (score 1):

So this issue can apparently be caused by having multiple copies of notepad++ installed. I was having this issue with HTML and CSS files, and it was very annoying. After reading this info here, I saw they were indeed being identified as json5 instead of html or css. So I did some further digging and found this post:

https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/13042

which explained the issue in detail being caused by an older version in C:/Program Files/

I was running notepad++ from D:/Program Files/ but I searched my system and found there indeed was another copy in C:  I decided to remove the copy from D: and updated the one on C: and switched to using that, and I no longer seem to be having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it empirically :

- Disable half of the plugins and restart
  Notepad++
- If the highlight disappears, or not, this will reduce the candidates
  to half
- Continue disabling half of the remaining candidates, until only one
  is left, and the job is done.

Comment: This is only the last resort.

Comment: It might be the fastest resort.

Comment: Usually the fastest is one of SE's sites. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same problem and found a solution that worked for me. Having read this article, I explored the Plugins Admin under Plugins > Plugins Admin.

Before I began tinkering with installed plugins, I noticed under the Updates tab that the 'SQLinForm' extension required an update.

Once I updated it and restarted Notepad++, all the orange was gone, thankfully!
HTH

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).